# asking user's permission use local notifications

Tags: ios, notifications

I have an alert that displays the first time the app is launched, to ask the user's permission to allow the app to send local notifications. I have it in `AppDelegate.m`. The alert is ok, but I have an error in the code to test which button was pressed (Yes or No).

I get an error at the `- (void)alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` line that says **Use of undeclared identifier** `alertview`.

Here's the code:

```
//ask user if its ok to send local notifications
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notifications?"
                                                  message:@"Is it ok for this app to send you reminder notifications? (You can change this in Settings)"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[message show];

//which button was clicked?
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [UIAlertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"No"])
    {
        NSLog(@"NO was selected.");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"notifications"]; //0 = off, 1 = on
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"YES was selected.");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"notifications"]; //0 = off, 1 = on
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace line:

```
NSString *title = [UIAlertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
```

with:

```
NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
```

`UIAlertView` class has no class method `buttonTitleAtIndex:`. It is an **instance method** which should be called on instances of `UIAlertView` class.

Also make sure that you conform to `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol if you want to make use of `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method.

**EDIT**:

Like @Sam suggested you can also make use of `buttonIndex` instead of button title which can be changed in the future leaving you with a bug if you don't update your `if` statements.

*Example*:

```
if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

**EDIT 2**:

Make sure you have a closing bracket "}" before method definition.

*Example*:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    ...
}  <= DONT FORGET TO TYPE A CLOSING BRACKET 

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex    
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You probably don't need to do the string compare either... a simple check for index is standard. I think here 0 == No, and 1 == Yes?

Comment: You don't NEED to, and I probably would do it slightly different, but if he decided to change the order of those buttons it would break if he was referencing the index, whereas this will still work as designed if he changes YES and NO to NO and YES.

Comment: Ok thanks so much for that advice.   My problem is the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol.  The above code is called in the appdelegate.m file - not the view controller file - so I haven't used the protocol yet - no doubt this is my problem.  But how should I use it?  Am I in the wrong file,  I wonder?  Can I do this in the appDelegate?

Comment: @ianM You conform to a protocol in a class by typing protocol name between less-than and greater-than signs after a class name, like so: ``@interface ClassName : Superclass <**PROTOCOL_NAME**>``. In case of ``AppDelegate`` conforming to ``UIAlertViewDelegate`` protocol, this would look like this: ``@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>``.

Comment: ok, thanks again!  I have set up the protocol as follows: @interface Picker_1AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> as you said and modified the clickedButtonAtIndex however I sill get an error on the -(void alertView line with the message "Use of undeclared identifier 'alertView'.  Any ideas?

Comment: @ianM do you have a closing brace "}" before method ``- (void)alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:``? Look at my edit ;)